# I have a 500 server error in Elastic Search

Tags: validation, elasticsearch, nosql, jwt, authorization

I'm having the following problem when I enter the page, I don't know what part of Elastic Search is causing it

```
NestedError: Error while validating Authorization header at 
boService.getSignKey.then.then.catch (/var/youmarket/fo-search/src/middleWares/validation.js:32:28)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
Caused By: JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/var/youmarket/fo-search/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:49:17)
    at Promise (/var/youmarket/fo-search/src/middleWares/validation.js:16:9)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at jwtPromise (/var/youmarket/fo-search/src/middleWares/validation.js:6:10)
    at boService.getSignKey.then (/var/youmarket/fo-search/src/middleWares/validation.js:26:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

Comment: are u sure its an elasticsearch error, seem more like an error in js

Comment: There was a problem in Laravel's Backend, I could fix it

Comment: If you found a solution for your issue, please consider adding an answer with your solution and accepting it :)

Comment: i was problem in backend with 1 function bad declaration, nothing more.
thanks.